# How to shift from one distro's grub to another's

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 14.04(say ubuntu-1) and set it with another Ubuntu 14.04(say ubuntu-2). Now everytime I boot my PC I see the grub boot menu from Ubuntu-2 but I want it to start from Ubuntu-1's grub. I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to boot into whichever one's grub you want to use and reinstall its GRUB. For example, boot into Ubuntu-2 and then run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Note that the above assumes you want your GRUB to be on `/dev/sda`. You should change that to whichever drive you want to install it on.

Comment: It shows me an error when I tried that. `Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system 'ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists. `

Comment: @7_R3X please [edit] your question and add more details about your system. Is this an UEFI install? Are you sure you even have `grub`? If you do have it, where is it installed?

Comment: Yeah! Pretty sure I've grub. And it's in the directory `/boot/grub` of both Ubuntu-1 and Ubuntu-2. Not sure about the UEFI install though. How do I check it?

Comment: @7_R3X do you have a `/sys/firmware/efi` directory? And please *[edit]* your question to add all this extra info as I asked. It's hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: @7_R3X hang on, what command did you run? Did you try something like `/dev/sda1` instead of `/dev/sda` as I suggested?

Comment: `/dev/sd1` is actually swap. I have Ubuntu-1 in `/dev/sda3` and yeah I tried it with `/dev/sda3` :/ Why? Did I go wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34755/discussion-between-terdon-and-7-r3x).

Comment: @7_R3X yes, you tried to install on a partition and not an MBR. I never said `sda1`, I said `sda`. Join me in the chat room above and we can figure it out.